# How to visualize abstract concepts?

Tags: algorithms

I'm a web developer and I struggle to visualize abstract concepts in my head.

By abstract concept, it can be:
- the backend model of a webapp (with several objects inter-connected to each other)
- repeated actions on a data structure (a sort on a array for example)

For example, I  wanted to implement a [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) last week.

At first, I tried to imagine an array, in my head.
It contained numbers and I tried to permute the numbers in my head. It was really hard.

Then I draw the permutations, it was still hard.

Then, I watched this excellent [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yIQuKSwPlro).

The teacher uses real glasses with numbers drawn on it.

I bought some cheap glasses, I draw numbers on them and I tried all the permutations.
Then, after a while, I was able to grasp a pattern, then I turned it into an algorithm that worked well.

In general, I know that I have a hard time representing mental models in my head.
When I draw it, it becomes A LOT easier
And if use real objects (like the glasses), then it's even more easier.

Unfortunately, there are some situations where I have no choice but representing mental models in my head.
For example, in a meeting with several collaborators, where we brainstorm about the different ways we could adapt the architecture of our web app to accomplish a cool feature.

I really want to improve my brain in this area, but I don't know how to do, apart from doing personal challenges with algorithms and designing web app models.

Do you use some specific methods to represent abstract concepts in your head ?

Do you know some books, some exercices or some ways to improve ?

Thank you very much guys.

Comment: There are methods like drawing mind maps, graphs, flowcharts, plots, UML diagrams, use case diagrams, class diagrams, etc. if you have tried them and feel comfortable that is good way, otherwise your question is a bit harder, becaues everyone uses slightly different internal representation. That said, answer with description of how someone thinks about abstract concepts might be of no use for you. Besides, there will be no possible measure of how good some answer is (so it is primarily opinion-based), which does not work well here. Also one question per post is the preffered way.

Comment: It is unclear to me if you 1) want to be able to simulate an algorithm in your head/by hand OR 2) want to be able to understand why the algorithm works.

Comment: Are sure that you're talking about the right type of abstraction?  A bubble sort isn't really in the same abstraction room as trying to imagine a 10 dimensional hypersphere, or what Carl Jung identified as evolutionary archetypes.

Comment: Evil Ok, I understand that there is no magical answer to this question. Billiska: It's rather answer 1. Ultimately, what I want to do is to solve problems with an algorithm. In order to do that, I have to be able to think about an algorithm, and "run" it in my head with a concrete scenario, to know if it works or not. Paul Uszak: I'm mostly talking about one-dimension arrays here, nothing fancy :)

Comment: It is a long shot and I do not know the rules there (and as reminder, please do not cross-post and check the on-topicness), the https://cseducators.stackexchange.com is about teaching CS, there are some promising questions about abstract concepts, object oriented paradigm etc. It may be worth to read.

Comment: Practice. It gets better after a while.